# Every sequence has a further subsequence converges in probability to $X$

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, probability-theory, measure-theory, convergence-divergence

Let $\{X_n \}$ be a sequence of random variables on $(\Omega,\mathcal{F})$ such that every sequence has a further subsequence converges in probability to $X$ is equivalent to stating that $X_n$ converges in probability to $X$.

I have done the if part as (almost sure convergence $\implies$ convergence in probability).
But I cannot figure out an argument for the only if part.

Answer (score 2):

This has nothing to do with probability theory (except for the  definition). $P(|X_n-X|>\epsilon) \to 0$ iff every subsequence of $(P(|X_n-X|>\epsilon))$ has a further subsequence tending to $0$ This is a property of sequences of real numbers.

Hint: Suppose $a_n $ does not tend to $a$. Then there exist $\epsilon >0$ and a subsequence $a_{n_k}$ such that $|a_{n_k}| >\epsilon$ for all $k$. It follows that no subsequence of $a_{n_k}$ can converge to $0$.

Comment: Yes, I get it.. This boils down to taking $P(|X_n-X|<\epsilon)$ as a sequence itself i.e. $a_n$ perhaps and apply the result on $a_n$ right?